# Django - Difference between Database backed sessions and Cookie Based Session?

Tags: django, session, cookies

Was going through Django Documentation and found this "https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/sessions/#using-database-backed-sessions". What is the difference between database backed sessions and cookie based sessions? What is the advantage of one over the other? And what are the disadvantages?

Comment: Would like to answer as per django. The default session backend is Database in django.django_session is table for the sessions.the session object in Request.session is a dictionary which is pickled and  endcoded and stored in database column, And each session is persisted through session id. Finally, each sessionid is stored in a cookie, which is sent on the first request to webpage.If you set store_session_on_each_request to True, for each request session id is sent through cookie.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A [Session](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_(computer_science)#Server_side_web_sessions) is used by websites to store [application state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_(computer_science)) for visitors across multiple page loads.

#### Cookie Sessions

- Store their data on the client/user end
- Work smoothly when you have a cluster of web servers
- Browsers typically limit cookies to a maximum size of around 4 kilobytes per domain, so limited session data size
- Cookies can be set to a long lifespan, which means that data stored in a session cookie could be stored for months if not years (Users can clear cookies though)
- Must be set with HttpOnly and Secure flags, otherwise can be easily stolen via XSS

#### Database Sessions

- Store their data server side
- One of your web servers handles the first request, other web servers in your cluster will not have the stored information unless centrally storing user session data
- Clients do not have access to the information you store about them and therefore better for sensitive data.
- Data doesn't have to travel from client to server on each request (clients just need to send an ID so the server can load the data)
- Can store more data, since stored on server instead of in a cookie

#### Cookie Sessions vs Database Sessions

```
| Feature                       | Cookie Sessions | Database Sessions |
|-------------------------------|-----------------|-------------------|
| Works without database        | Yes             | No                |
| Can store sensitive user data | No*             | Yes               |
```

* Can store pointers referencing sensitive user data on the server, just not the sensitive data itself.

Both Cookie Sessions and Database Sessions work the same way, the only difference is where the data is stored.
[Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/latest/topics/http/sessions/#configuring-the-session-engine) defaults to Database Sessions while [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/quickstart/#sessions) defaults to Cookie Sessions.

More information:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_(computer_science)
http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/qt/session_cookie.htm
http://wonko.com/post/why-you-probably-shouldnt-use-cookies-to-store-session-data
http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/10/1/0

Comment: With the database sessions, if all of the web servers are sharing a single database, why wouldn't the other web servers in your cluster have the stored information?

Comment: @KrisF they do share the cookie if you're using a single database. The cookies are also not cleared (by default) when the user closes their browser.

Comment: I don't think cookie sessions can be easily hacked. According to the docs, a MAC is used to ensure authenticity of the data that you receive. So you can be sure that you're getting data that you set, not that was tampered with. OTOH, it's super easy to *read* cookie session data.